# How to set ".last-seen-products" in vertical orientation

Tags: shopware

I am trying to set the vertical orientation for **".last-seen-products"** but didn't have any luck finding a doc talking about it. If I'm not wrong, the **.last-seen-products** slider is initialized in **jquery.last-seen-products.js** file at line 181: **me.productSlider.initSlider();**

```
/**
         * Creates a list of all collected articles and calls
         * the product slider plugin.
         *
         * @public
         * @method createProductList
         */
        createProductList: function () {
            var me = this,
                opts = me.opts,
                itemKey = 'lastSeenProducts-' + opts.shopId + '-' + opts.baseUrl,
                productsJson = me.storage.getItem(itemKey),
                products = productsJson ? JSON.parse(productsJson) : [],
                len = Math.min(opts.productLimit, products.length);

            if (len > 1) {
                me.$el.removeClass('is--hidden');
            }

            $.each(products, function(i, product) {
                if (product.articleId === opts.currentArticle.articleId) {
                    return;
                }

                me.$container.append(me.createTemplate(product));
            });

            me.productSlider.initSlider();

            $.publish('plugin/swLastSeenProducts/onCreateProductList', [ me ]);
        }
```

That piece of code, is calling the Product slider plugin, so how can I pass the vertical orientation option into **me.productSlider.initSlider()** ??? I was expecting something like me.productSlider.initSlider(**{orientation: "vertical"}**) or is it a different way to do it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I just had to add to the container div a data-orientation="vertical" to make it work. There are more options also to add as data attributes in the container div, you can take a look in the jquery.product-slider.js and check the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of those sliders look at the orientation of the HTML-Container - the image slider for example.

In order to make the javascript work in a vertical orientation, you should use CSS and style the container (your slider element) to be vertical (e.g. having a smaller width than height).